# What is a single instance (row) of a truth table is called (an adventure solving a problem of terminology)

Tags: logic, terminology, self-learning, learning

Just now, for whatever reason I'm having issues finding out the terminology of what name/s is given to a single instance (a row) from a truth table.

My question is focused on the (system and steps) in (solving the problem itself) -- in a generically-Λ-succinct way. I only have a GED's worth of formal schooling and was never taught a sophisticated/structured method of obtaining knowledge like in the unknown above. My strategy has always been solely intuition, then brute force through permutations. But when intuition fails, brute force fails likely.

I'm unsure if this should be asked on another exchange, I started here with desire to get the perspective of the *structured*-mathematician, and the original problem's relation to logic.

Back towards my original problem...

#### Here's where I've tried Googling and Wikipedia:

Googling of course brings up lots of info. Checking [Wikipedia (Truth Table)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) my eyes get distracted with the amount that I don't understand yet. Ctrl-F'ing failed to match 'related words I could think of.

I did come across the term *truth-value*. I understand it's related to my answer, but I'm not able to verify it's scope of relationship.

.

(?)Possibly the study of Ontology would have provided me the skills to solve such a problem?

#### Example of the epoch question

Say for AND: What would a single line (i.e., False Λ False = False) be called?

```
  X |  Y
| F | F | = F
| F | T | = F
| T | F | = F
| T | T | = T
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  It's called a row of a truth table.  In your particular example, I would call it the first row of the table.  If you mean that you want the name of the statement $F\wedge F =F$ I would say that's rather like asking for the name of the statement $1+3=4$.  If you are asking something else, please try to clarify it for me.

Comment: Oh,....possibly there is no term. If there isn't a more specific term for *row* of the true table then I'm not sure there's anything to say... I was expecting that a single row would have other attributes and significance's that would give it a unique identifier in conversation/communication/documentation, especially if it's in an environment where checking each row is costly.

Comment: As @saulspatz comments, there is no particular name for a row in a truth table. Responding to your question more generally, mathematicians rarely have to verify big truth tables line by line. Most serious proofs, even in logic, are written mostly in words.

Comment: A row in the truth table is a [*truth assignment* (or : *valuation*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Great. Possibly their real world usage isn't most common...  As part of my question. Say hypothetically you knew everything you do now, but you had never learned those terms before, but you also knew they *probably* existed. How would you obtain this knowledge (as a mathematician) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in the truth table is generally referred to as an "interpretation." This is what I've seen in lectures and in papers.

Comment: How would you have figured this out (as a mathematician) if you had never learned this term before, but you knew it probably existed?  Is there any other method besides starting from the bottom and learning one's way up until the whole subject matter makes sense (even then that method may not be enough).

Comment: If this subject matter was foreign to me, and I wanted to learn the term for a row in a truth table, then I would start by googling a description of what I was looking for, as you did. If that didn't work, I would skim some introductory material via wiki or a textbook. If that didn't work, I would skim some papers via google scholar. If that didn't work, I would post a message on the stack exchange, haha. I don't believe it's a good use of one's time to start from ground zero and learn your way up to simply learn a simple piece of information such as that. I think you took the right approach!

Comment: If you are satisfied with your answer, please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Comment: In programming I try to use variable names reflecting on the subject itself. I like pretty and elegant code.  Often times I get stuck trying to figure out what to call something, and I'm (too much of a perfectionist to write badly named variables) and (I have issues calling it quits).

Answer (score 1):

Each row in a truth table stands for one combinatorial possibility of assigning truth values to the propositional letters that occur in the formula. This is precisely a **variable assignment function** aka **valuation function** aka **interpretation** as defined in the semantics of propositional logic. You may refer to a row as this if you want to make explicit that a row in the truth table stands for one assignment, though more usually when you're talking about truth tables it's really just called "row x in the truth table".

Comment: Usually, "variable assignment" is used in the semantics of FOL for free variables.